# Create new team project with custom process is failing

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfs-workitem

Im unable to create a new team project with the custom process as it is failing with "Project creation operation failed". But the new project creation works fine with any existing process template(i.e., Agile, Basic e.t.c.,)

The steps i followed to create a new process template

1. Export Agile process template
2. Edited ProcessTemplate.xml with new name, version and GUID. No other changes done.
3. Saved the file and created a zip folder.
4. Uploaded it in TFS under "Upload process template".
5. While uploading showed the below warning, have clicked continue ignoring the warning
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]
6. The upload is successful and can see my new process listed.
7. Selecting the new process template and create new project is failing with the below error.
   [![enter image description here][2]][2]

As the error doesnt have much info , im not sure what is missing. As i have downloaded a teplate and just changed name,version and GUID. Any help on this regards will be very helpful. Thanks in advance
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m2PI.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6eyG.png

Comment: Hi @Padmanaban, what do you mean 'edit ProcessTemplate.xml with version and GUID'? Did you mean edit this '<version minor="" major="*" type="****"/>' for 'version and GUID'? I change it and the name but with no error to create new projects. Could you tell the specific value you try? And for confirmation, you didn't modify the "syncnamechanges" attribute of "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReviewBy" in the file "WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\CodeReviewResponse.xml"？Thanks in advance.

Comment: To exclude the issue, could you directly export the Agile process, without extract the file then import to replace the Agile process to see whether the original process works well. If so, then please only edit my meinoned '<version minor="" major="*" type="****"/>' and name for a try to see whether it works.

Comment: Hi @AntoniaWu-MSFT Thanks for your response. I have skipped customizing the process and adding a new workitem through Visual studio and customizing the xml file

Comment: I am so glad to hear that you find a solution. If it is convenient, you could kindly share it and mark it as answer. This may help others who might meet the issue in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for providing this method for importing custom process of TFS server. Just as a reminder, you could [accept it an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)  :>

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution. My TFS server is on premise and the inherited process is not available. Hence installed TFS process template editor ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor ). This creates a new sub menu in Tools named process editor. Where i exported the work item. renamed and imported it with desired elements.